# Reference request: Associahedron

Tags: reference-request, cluster-algebras

I am reading Sergey Fomin's and Nathan Reading's paper  [Root Systems and Generalized Associahedra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505518.pdf).

I need a good reference for associahedron of classical types. Besides, whether there are some conclusions for associahedron of exceptional types.

Comment: I'm wondering if Gunter Ziegler's Lectures on Polytopes has something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original source would be Fomin-Zelevinsky, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111053.  Note that, for them, the "associahedron" is really just a fan (the normal fan to the simple polytope associahedron).  The first realization of the associahedra as polytopes was given by Chapoton-Fomin-Zelevinsky, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202004.  There has been subsequent work by others (including me).

Comment: Thank you very much. I find your paper: Permutahedra and generalized associahedra http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810002586?via%3Dihub.

Answer (score 1):

Not direct but as a side reference, I suggest you take a look into [this seminal work](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507163) by Alex Postnikov.